# In a triangle one angle contains as many grades as another

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle one angle contains as many grades as another contains degrees and the third contains as many centesimal seconds as there are sexagesimal seconds in the sum of the other two,find the number of radians in each angle.

I tried doing this ,but i got 0.138 pi rad as the measure of the first angle ,while the actual answer is 0.3577 pi rad .

Can someone please help

Comment: By grades, I gather that you mean the percent grade of one angle is equal to the number of degrees in another. Since you mention degrees, I think radians is irrelevant. We have x, the angle equal to the sum of the first two, as $3600(y+z)$, where y is degrees of the $2_{nd}$ angle and z is the first angle where $100*sin(\alpha )=z$. If these are the definitions of your angles, then a little [tedious] algebra and trig should be able to solve the problem for you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format numbers and math expressions.